# TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/ admin/index.html

Tags: django, django-templates

I am unable to access the admin interface in django 1.1.1 using `localloop:8000/admin`. It was working fine on Ubuntu 8.4 then I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 and the problem occurred.

In `settings.py` I have:

```
import os.path
PROJECT_DIR=os.path.dirname(__file__)

TEMPLATE_DIRS =(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'templates'))
```

This  was working fine on Ubuntu 8.04 but not in Ubuntu 10.10.

Any ideas on what goes wrong? Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'hotweb.accounts',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'messages',
 'hotweb.jchat']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.http.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source:
/home/scorpion/Desktop/hotweb/templates/admin/index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source:
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html (File exists)



Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  196.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  186.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  374.             context_instance=context_instance
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  103.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  81.     source, origin = find_template_source(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template_source
  74.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist, name

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
Exception Value: admin/index.html
```

---

here is the trace back

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'hotweb.accounts',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'messages',
 'hotweb.jchat']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.http.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source:
/home/scorpion/Desktop/hotweb/templates/admin/index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source:
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html (File exists)



Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  196.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  186.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  374.             context_instance=context_instance
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  103.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  81.     source, origin = find_template_source(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template_source
  74.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist, name

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
Exception Value: admin/index.html
```

Comment: That's kind of a strange path and/or URL: "/admin/ admin/index.html", since it's got a space in it and the admin is repeated. Did *anything* else change besides going from 8.04 to 10.10? Different Python? Different Django?

Comment: noo nothing only the platform is changed from 8.04 to 10.10

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that `APP_DIRS` is set to `True` in the `Templates`

Comment: The Templates settings didn't exist at that time

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that's odd since `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting doesn't have anything to do with the admin app.

If you're sure it's those 3 lines, the only possible thing I see wrong is `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is supposed to be a tuple (yours is a string), but on 1.2.3 it doesn't cause any problems.

You say "the problem occurred in settings.py"... but
I don't see where a TemplateDoesNotExist error would appear from the lines you pasted -- can you post the full traceback? Which line of code triggered TemplateDoesNotExist? How do you know it was settings.py?

I think the problem lies outside of your 3 lines.

PS: I can't comment since I have <50 rep.

Comment: i mean that all of my templates exists in the above path directory but i dont know where is admin template this same thing works with the 8.04 but not with 10.10 ubuntu

Comment: majorly stumped. /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html (File exists) <-- interesting line.